# Xamarin iOS, Firebase FCM - Token refresh deleting InstanceId: unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using **Firebase Cloud Messaging** with **Xamarin Forms/iOS** (package version 2.0.8). I correctly receive messages, and I can intercept token refresh with:

```
Firebase.InstanceID.InstanceId.Notifications.ObserveTokenRefresh((sender, e) => { });
```

declared in my AppDelegate.

I'm trying to **force fcm token refresh** at every login because I want to be sure that at every login each user has a clean token assigned (and sent to the server). In Android I made it working, but on iOS when I try to delete the InstanceId with:

```
var handler = new InstanceIdDeleteHandler((error) => {
    Console.WriteLine(error?.DebugDescription);
});

InstanceId.SharedInstance.DeleteId(handler);
var token = InstanceId.SharedInstance.Token;
```

I receive the following error:

> +[FIRInstanceIDCheckinPreferences preferencesFromKeychainContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x102daab28 Xamarin.iOS: Received
>   unhandled ObjectiveC exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
>   +[FIRInstanceIDCheckinPreferences preferencesFromKeychainContents:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x102daab28

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of blasphemies I found the solution, maybe it could be useful for somebody else.

It's necessary to add a method in the **AppDelegate**:

```
[Export("messaging:didRefreshRegistrationToken:")]
public void DidRefreshRegistrationToken(Messaging mess, string token)
{
}
```

It's never hit so it can be empty, but without declaring this one apparently it's not possible to force the fcm token refresh deleting the InstanceId.